# How to get specific variable from JSON object?

Tags: java, json, resttemplate

I'm trying to get some data from other API and I need to get StatusCode from JSON object but I'm getting null object.

I was trying to create new class with StatusCode variable but I'm getting null.
I'm trying to get this data :

```
Data(data=[{"Number":"20450143160505","DateCreated":"11-06-2019 10:14:27","DocumentWeight":0.5,"CheckWeight":0,"SumBeforeCheckWeight":0,"PayerType":"Recipient","RecipientFullName":"","RecipientDateTime":"","ScheduledDeliveryDate":"12-06-2019","PaymentMethod":"Cash","CargoDescriptionString":"","CargoType":"Parcel","CitySender":"Сокільники","CityRecipient":"Київ","WarehouseRecipient":"Відділення №150 (до 30 кг): вул. Антоновича, 43 (м.\"Олімпійська\")","CounterpartyType":"PrivatePerson","Redelivery":1,"RedeliverySum":"","RedeliveryNum":"","RedeliveryPayer":"","AfterpaymentOnGoodsCost":"","ServiceType":"WarehouseWarehouse","UndeliveryReasonsSubtypeDescription":"","WarehouseRecipientNumber":150,"LastCreatedOnTheBasisNumber":"","LastCreatedOnTheBasisDocumentType":"","LastCreatedOnTheBasisPayerType":"","LastCreatedOnTheBasisDateTime":"","LastTransactionStatusGM":"","LastTransactionDateTimeGM":"","WarehouseRecipientInternetAddressRef":"916c7c93-8460-11e4-acce-0050568002cf","MarketplacePartnerToken":"","DateScan":"12:23 12.06.2019","ClientBarcode":"","SenderAddress":"","RecipientAddress":"","CounterpartySenderDescription":"","CounterpartyRecipientDescription":"","CounterpartySenderType":"Organization","PaymentStatus":"","PaymentStatusDate":"","AmountToPay":"","AmountPaid":"","WarehouseRecipientRef":"916c7c94-8460-11e4-acce-0050568002cf","DocumentCost":40,"AnnouncedPrice":"","OwnerDocumentNumber":"","DateFirstDayStorage":"2019-06-21","InternationalDeliveryType":"","DaysStorageCargo":"","RecipientWarehouseTypeRef":"841339c7-591a-42e2-8233-7a0a00f0ed6f","StorageAmount":"","StoragePrice":"","VolumeWeight":"0.50","SeatsAmount":"1","OwnerDocumentType":"","ActualDeliveryDate":"2019-06-12 12:23:22","DateReturnCargo":"","CardMaskedNumber":"","Status":"Прибув у відділення","StatusCode":"7","RefEW":"8ed817ef-8c18-11e9-91ff-0025b501a04b","RedeliveryPaymentCardRef":"","RedeliveryPaymentCardDescription":"","CreatedOnTheBasis":"","DatePayedKeeping":"2019-06-21 00:00:00","OnlineCreditStatusCode":"","OnlineCreditStatus":""}])
```

**Method to get data** :

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                Data string = restTemplate.postForObject(blalba,blabla,Data.class)
```

And my class

```java
public class Data {
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private JsonNode data;
//get set
}
```

Comment: You should probably replace *blalba* with something meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve it:

### Using a `Map<String, Object>`

You could read the response payload as a `Map<String, Object>`:

```java
ParameterizedTypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> responseType = 
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};

Map<String, Object> responsePayload = 
        restTemplate.exchange(purchaseRequestDetailsEndpoint, HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(requestPayload), responseType);

String statusCode = responsePayload.get("StatusCode");
```

### Mapping only the properties you need

Define a class mapping the properties you need:

```java
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResponsePayload {

    @JsonProperty("StatusCode")
    private String statusCode;
}
```

And read the response payload using the class defined above:

```java
ResponsePayload responsePayload = 
        restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, ResponsePayload.class);

String statusCode = responsePayload.getStatusCode();
```

Alternatively you could map the properties you need and store the rest in a map:

```java
@Data
public class ResponsePayload {

    @JsonProperty("StatusCode")
    private String statusCode;

    @JsonAnySetter
    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    public Object get(String key) {
        return properties.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: When im using first way to do it in restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, responseType) iw got:Cannot resolve method 'postForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>)'

Comment: and when im using your second way im getting null

Comment: @НазарЛихолат Sorry, my bad. Use `exchange()` instead. My answer has been updated accordingly.